# HBITMAP hbm=LoadImage function returns NULL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, null, loadimage

I'm having issues displaying a bitmap on the screen. When I complile and run its not displaying anything so I tried debugging step by step and found that the below code is the issue.

```
HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, 
                        "C:\\Users\\Jemma\\Desktop\\Maze Game\\Assets\\TILE_01.bmp", 
                        IMAGE_BITMAP, 
                        SWidth, SHeight, 
                        LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION); 
    if (hbm == NULL || m_Surface == NULL)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
```

When I get to this function under autos first it says hbm=0xcccccccc{unused=???} (I'm assuming it's due to not being initialised as this comes up when I get to the line so I haven't stepped into it at this point - Just thought I'd put it in just incase) after I've stepped into this line it says hbm = NULL, and the GetLastError function returns 0 which I've read means function was successful. I've tried passing NULL instead of hInstance, I've tried passing the filename in as LPCSTR szFileName -- I declared it as LPCSTR szFileName("C:\Users\Jemma\Desktop\Maze Game\Assets\TILE_01.bmp").
Absolutely no idea what to try next. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `0xcccccccc` is the standard value in debug builds for an uninitialized stack variable.  Your code looks correct. I even tested it with my own image.  When `LoadImage` returns NULL  You need to call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the error code for why it failed.  Are you sure that TILE_01.bmp exists and is a real BMP file and not some other format?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I had a PNG file that I converted to BITMAP. I've just downloaded a BMP file and it seems to work fine now :) Thanks again

Comment: MFC is very limited on what image files it can accept. If your image has transparencies, you will need to save the file in a very specific format as in my own comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953499/mfc-toolbar-icon-not-visible-in-visual-studio-2015#comment71572831_41953499

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that your image is real bmp file and can be opened with image viewer. Then try this to load that HBITMAP using [LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
const char* filename = "C:\\Users\\Jemma\\Desktop\\Maze Game\\Assets\\TILE_01.bmp";
HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, filename,
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (hbm == NULL)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
```

Note, you need to use 0, 0 for sizes when you use `LR_DEFAULTSIZE`, also, when loading from file you need to use `LR_LOADFROMFILE`. All of these are mentioned in [documentation of LoadImage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

When stepping through with debugger if you get something unexpected you need to check [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx). If you are stepping through with VS debugger, you can simply add `@err` in watch window and you'll always see the last error without changing your code. You can also add it as `@err,hr` and it will show you readable description of the error that happened.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I followed your advice and after another few hours of debugging :/ I've found that after the loadImage() function @err,hr says: "ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE : The handle is invalid"

Comment: @Jemma try to use `LoadImage((HINSTANCE)NULL, ...`

Comment: Hi, just tried that and it still says invalid handle, I've also tried `LoadImage((HINSTANCE) hInstance,...  ` just incase and it still comes up with invalid handle, I've noted that under autos while debugging the hInstance value says Maze Game.exe!0x00810000(Type information missing from symbol file) {unused=946030} not sure if that could be causing issues

Comment: @Jemma Are you still having this issue? if not how did you fix it?

Comment: I got it working by saving the bitmap with 24 bits only. With 32 bits it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* filename = "C:\\Users\\Jemma\\Desktop\\Maze Game\\Assets\\TILE_01.bmp";
HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, filename,
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
if (bmp== NULL)
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    return 1;
}

I am using the same code as above mentioned but LoadImage() is returning NULL and getting lasterror =2 , even i am sure file is already there from belowcode:

string filePath = "D:\\ACC_car_Ego.bmp";
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(filePath))    // does filePath actually exist?
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    else
        DWORD lastError1 = GetLastError();
```